# mongo - unique name field base on parent_id field

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection **parents** with sample documents

```
===FIRST DOCUMENT===
_id: 1111,
name: Parent 1
===SECOND DOCUMENT===
_id: 2222,
name: Parent 2
```

I have a collection **children** with sample documents

```
===FIRST DOCUMENT===
_id: 123123131321,
parent_id: 1111,
name: Child 1

===SECOND DOCUMENT===
_id: 29139114142,
parent_id: 2222,
name: Child 2
```

I want to make field `name` unique when We have the same `parent_id`

For example:

```
_id: 10239120321da,
parent_id: 2222,
name: Child 2
```

Attempt to insert above document into children collection should throws exception `DuplicateKeyError`.
I read something about Partial Index but I don't know that this is the proper path.
I'm using python with flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mongoDB collection that is named "collectionName",

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { parent_id: 1, name: 1}, { unique: true } )
```